# No database selected, even though explictly stated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query running in a script, and when it's run in mysql workbench it works fine.

However, running the script results in 'no database selected' error in powershell. I've followed the error prompts but you can see in my query I explicitly state the database for each table, i.e. (ambition.ambition_totals).

Is there another constraint I should add to this?

```
$stmt3 = mysqli_prepare($conn2,
             "UPDATE ambition.ambition_totals a
                INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT 
                    c.user AS UserID,
                    COUNT(*) AS dealers,
                    ROUND((al.NumberOfDealers / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2)  AS percent
                FROM jfi_dealers.contact_events c
                JOIN jackson_id.users u
                ON c.user = u.id
                JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers d
                ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
                LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
                  FROM jackson_id.attr_list AS al
                  JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
                  WHERE al.attr_id = 14
                  GROUP BY user_id) AS al
                ON al.user_id = c.user
                GROUP BY UserID) as cu
                on cu.UserID = a.ext_id 
                SET a.dealers_contacted = cu.dealers,
                  a.percent_up_to_date = cu.percent;
                        ") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
```

Comment: Did you specify a database in your MySQLi connection? If not, you  need to.

Comment: you should use [mysqli_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) to select a database first...or specify it when creating the connection as @JayBlanchard said

Comment: No, you should always specify the database in the connection. `mysqli_select_db()` is only for changes. ([This function should only be used to change the default database for the connection. You can select the default database with 4th parameter in `mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the database name as the fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect()`

Here's an example that assumes you're connecting on localhost:

```
$conn2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "your_username", "your_password", "ambition");
```

or do `mysqli_select_db("ambition")` before your `mysqli_prepare` statement if `ambition` was not your default database.

Comment: No, you should always specify the database in the connection. `mysqli_select_db()` is only for changes. ([This function should only be used to change the default database for the connection. You can select the default database with 4th parameter in `mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php))

Comment: Thanks. I was only giving the possible solutions as OP didn't show how the connection was made. I'm thinking the db wasn't specified when it was created (as it's optional).

Comment: It, as I have pointed out, NOT optional. Even though the documentation doesn't state it, you *must* state a default database during the connection. Then, and only then, can you use `mysqli_change_db()` to change the default database. I cannot tell you how many time people have run into this error and have corrected it by specifying a default during the connection.

Comment: Aren't all the parameters optional? Says [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp) they are

Comment: It says that, but it is not correct and you shouldn't use W3Schools as your source.http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php You have to combine this with the information from the docs for `mysqli_change_db()`

Comment: @RogersCadenhead Please do not add code to answers during edits as it is an attempt to answer the question. Instead, write an answer with the code you were going to add in an edit of another's answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I just tested it by creating a connection without specifying a default db, and then using `mysqli_select_db()` and it works, no errors or warnings

Comment: I understand that, but please read the docs. This is not guaranteed behavior.